# How to print a value from column A(Sheet 2) in a cell after comparing if value from column D(Sheet 1) is in column D(Sheet2)?

Tags: google-sheets

The value to be printed in column A(sheet2) is on the same row as column D(sheet 2)

So far I have this, it prints a random value from column A on sheet 2

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,Sheet2!D:D,1,FALSE)),FALSE,Sheet2!A:A)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!D:D, {Sheet2!D:D, Sheet2!A:A}, 2, 0)))
```